# Distinctcount with multiple filters on the same variables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to figure out how to add another layer to this DAX measure. I have a measure that counts the distinct occurrences of a unique ID where the sequence count is 2 and the source isn't blank. What I need is to add another statement that also narrows it down to occurrences where all the above is true, and when the sequence was 1 AND the source **was** blank for that earlier occurrence.
All instances where a sequence is 2 will have a sequence of 1, but not all of them will have had a blank source when the sequence was 1.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('table1'[uniqueID]),'table1'[sequence_count]=2, NOT(ISBLANK('table1'[source])))
```

Thanks in advance!!

EDIT: Here's an example table of data
[exampledata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap3sx.png)
The expected output here would be 1.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data in a tabular form and the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is reading this, I figured it out! I added an Index column after sorting by unique id and then by sequence count. I then used the following to create a new column:

`Previous Source with Blank = IF(table1[sequence_count]>1, CALCULATE(MAX(table1[source]), FILTER(table1, table1[Index] = EARLIER(table1[Index]) -1)), BLANK())`

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you request correct, you need a OR statement.

```
Measure = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('table1'[uniqueID]), FLITER( ALL('table1'), ('table1'[sequence_count]=2 && NOT(ISBLANK('table1'[source])) || ('table1'[sequence_count]=1 && ISBLANK('table1'[source])  ))
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I don't think that quite gives me what I'm looking for, but I'm realizing my question would be more clear with an example of the data, for example I've added a table in my original question to help.
I would want the count of unique IDs where sequence_count=2 AND souce =/=blank AND where there is a sequence_count=1 ANDsource=blank. I feel like I may be overthinking this.